# How to add tab-control on a form of QML-application?

Tags: tabs, qml, qt-creator

I’m working in Qt Creator 3.4.2 (on Qt 5.5.0) on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Qt Creator -> create project - application Qt Quick - Qt Quick 2.4

I have to add on mainform some tab-control element (and then modify it in WYSIWYG-mode, put into it other controls etc.), but on the "types QML"-palette i don't see nothing like this

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Qt Quick - Controls" section in Qt Quick Designer, as shown below:

[image]

If you don't see that, perhaps you're actually using a Qt version older than 5.1?